# FBX Model looks small, when scale is different. How can I make it look same?

Tags: three.js, fbx

I have used Threejs to load FBX 3D model in scene. Due to different scale of the 3D model, it looks different in viewer.

See the photo:
[image]

Proper FBX with scale 1 : [Download FBX MODEL 1](https://in.pothigara.com/public/5f991484a0d40e0e988e1722/3dProduct/fbx/a31fb035-78a8-48e8-95eb-14db1e4c845c.fbx)

Problematic FBX with scale 0.1 : [Download FBX MODEL 2](https://in.pothigara.com/public/5f991484a0d40e0e988e1722/3dProduct/fbx/6675f9da-37cf-4629-a1ac-79ecf0772442.fbx)

Both models should look in same scale, dimension, position and rotation of 3D model?

- How to handle Camera?
- How to handle lights? (Currently, there are 2 lights in the viewer.)

Here is the demo link for code review:

```
      let fbxLoader = new FBXLoader();

      fbxLoader.load(
        objectUrl, //1
        object => {

          scene.add(object);
          object.traverse(it => {
            if (it.isMesh) {
              it.receiveShadow = true;
              it.castShadow = true;
              scope.os = object.scale;
              
            }
          })

          let boxHelper = new THREE.Box3Helper(new THREE.Box3());

          boxHelper.visible = true;
          boxHelper.box.setFromObject(object);

          plane.position.y = boxHelper.box.min.y;

        },
        xhr => {
//          console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
        },
        // called when loading has errors
        error => {
          console.log("An error happened" + error);
        }
      );
```

My JsFiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/43eqnp2f/